# Slice image with Wand

Tags: python, wand

I want to extract multiple parts of an image with Wand.

I've just found a function for cropping (in-place) the image `img.crop(left, top, right, bottom)` but note the slicing one as they say [in the doc](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.crop).

> Note
>
> If you want to crop the image but not in-place, use slicing
>   operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`test_slice_crop`](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/blob/master/tests/image_test.py#L626) method in the test directory for examples.

```py
with Image(filename='source.jpg') as img:
    with img[100:200, 100:200] as cropped:
        # The `cropped' is an instance if wand.image.Image,
        # and can be manipulated independently of `img' instance.
        pass
```

**Edit**

For completion, [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) is a built-in function in python to represent a set of iterations (i.e. `a[start:stop:step]`). In [wand](/questions/tagged/wand), this is used to allow short-hand matrix iterations

```py
wand_instance[x:width, y:height]
```

Here's an example of generating 10px columns...

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="rose:") as rose:
    x = 0
    chunk_size = 10
    while True:
        try:
            with rose[x:x+chunk_size, 0:rose.height] as chunk:
                chunk.save(filename='rose_{0}.png'.format(x))
                x += chunk_size
        except IndexError:
            break
```

[image: sliced image]